# In rdl need next line if data is coming with \n

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc, rdl

In RDL if data is coming with 
 tag or \n then I want that as next line with a line gap.
Data coming as:-
Mobility-Dicharge(CJ)20-39% impaired.\nG840-Mobility-Projected(CJ)20-30% impaired.

Expected result in RDL:-

Mobility-Dicharge(CJ)20-39% impaired.

G840-Mobility-Projected(CJ)20-30% impaired.

similar image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3XeQ.png)

Comment: I can't test at the moment but have you tries replacing the \n with char(10 + char(13)

Comment: I used vbCrLf it's working now, thanks for your suggestion as well.